# Need to get href from HTML through section id

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, katalon-studio, getattribute

I need some help with getting href from HTML in my automatic test. 
My test should get specific urls (where we can find product with some options) from website which have id = "product-page". I have some method which should work, but it doesn't.

HTML snippet:

```html
<section id="product-page">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
<ul class="breadcrumb">
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/e-cigs-vaping-devices">E cigs vaping devices</a></li><li><a href="/e-cigs-vaping-devices/logic-pro-vaporizer">Logic pro vaporizer</a></li></ul></div></div></div>
```

And the method:

```html
public ArrayList<String> verifyProductSection(String divID) {
 
 KeywordUtil.logInfo("Get all Products links");
 String ModifiedString="";
 ModifiedString=divID.toLowerCase();
 
 WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver();
 
 List<String>ActualProductsLinks = new ArrayList<String>();
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("product-page"));
 List<WebElement> options =        element.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
 System.out.println(options.size());
 
 int ActualLinksSize = 0;
 
  for (WebElement we : options) {
  
  String strLinkName = we.getText();
  //println strLinkName.isEmpty();
   
  if (strLinkName == null || strLinkName.isEmpty()){
   }else{
 
   ActualProductsLinks.add(strLinkName);
   ActualLinksSize=ActualLinksSize+1;
   println (ActualLinksSize + " : Product Link Name : " + strLinkName);
   }
  }
    println ActualLinksSize;
}
```

Comment: Can you pease add some extra details on what problem you have and what you help you need regarding that.

Comment: Since you haven't described what you are doing much, I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. Additionally some errors and a better explanation is the basis for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the actual issue is). **Please edit your post accordingly**

Comment: Ok, done. Sorry, I will keep in mind :)

Comment: Just use this :  List<WebElement> links =      driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));  This will return you all links.

Comment: But I need to get one of them - and that link is under section id. 
When I use your solution I will receive many of them.
If I'm wrong please correct me :)

Comment: Which specific urls are you looking for? the _href_ attributes? e.g. `/`, `/e-cigs-vaping-devices` and `/e-cigs-vaping-devices/logic-pro-vaporizer`?

Comment: Yes, but you can get one object from there which you can able to find by index. OR If the links are not dynamic go through the xpath.

Comment: @DebanjanB - I'm looking for href:  /e-cigs-vaping-devices/logic-pro-vaporizer

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood your question. you want to extract all the links from the mentioned section.

Use below code and let me know if further queries.

```
WebElement section  = driver.findElement(By.id("product-page"));

List<WebElement> links = section.findElement(By.cssSelector(".breadcrumb a"));

System.out.println("total links : " + links.size());

for(int i=0 ; i<links.size(); i++)
{
     System.out.println("Linktext : " + links.get(i).getText());
     System.out.println("Link href : " + links.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
}
```

Comment: It's not working, I getting error like this:
"org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"product-page"}
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)"

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the *href* attribute which is **`/e-cigs-vaping-devices/logic-pro-vaporizer`** you can use the following solution:

- `xpath`:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//section[@id='product-page']//ul[@class='breadcrumb']//a[contains(.,'Logic pro vaporizer')]")).getAttribute("href"));
  ```

---

### Update

You can create a custom function and call it whereever needed as follows:

- Function :

  ```
  public void print_href(String productName)
  {
      System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//section[@id='product-page']//ul[@class='breadcrumb']//a[contains(.='" + productName + "')]")).getAttribute("href"));
  }
  ```
- Calling the function :

  ```
  print_href("Logic pro vaporizer")
  //or
  print_href("E cigs vaping devices")
  ```

Comment: Ok, but one thing - I have many urls with different href's and I want to create some custom method. This one is great, but for specific product page.

Comment: @Weirdo_Mrln Checkout my answer update and let me know the status